# How to log/view ICE connectivity check messages in Chrome for WebRTC application?

Tags: webrtc, stun

**My understanding:**
In WebRTC, SDP is used to relay ice candidates to remote peers after they are gathered by the local peer. The   connectivity checks thereafter are performed using STUN binding requests.  I can log the SDP received/sent using Javascript but these are merely ICE candidates.

**Question**:
How do I log or view the ICE connectivity check (STUN, RFC 5389) messages in Chrome? I understand that I can install Wireshark or some such tool to log all network traffic but I think there must be a better direct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to visit chrome://webrtc-internals and click "Download the PeerConnection updates and stats data" Button.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way you can get the STUN packets directly, but you can somewhat monitor what is going on via the `getStats` API!

[RTCIceCandidatePairStats](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/#candidatepair-dict*) you have `requestsReceived` and `requestsSent` so you can figure out some stuff from that.

I don't think we will ever get an API to actually get the packets though.